# Change resolution with Chrome_OS VMware Appliance?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I just downloaded the VMWare appliance for Chrome OS.i686-0.4.223.  There seems to be no way to change the screen resolution from 800x600.  VMWare tells me that the VMWare Tools are out of date.

I tried shutting down the machine and adding the CD Rom drive so I could add the VMWare Tools, per the instructions in VMWare. Turns out you need to install `gcc` and `kernel-source` --- but even then, I can't get the VMWare tools to compile, because the source code for the kernel that the Chrome_OS is running isn't in the repository.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also just tried Chrome OS (literally, about 20 minutes ago) in VirtualBox, and I couldn't change the resolution either, no matter what settings I chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary workaround I used xrandr. Type Ctrl-Alt-t to access the shell. At the command prompt type "xrandr" and press enter to get a list of available resolutions. On my laptop I enter "xrandr -s 1024x768."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using VMware's options?

When you edit your Virtual Machine Settings, open **Display settings**, and set the maximum resolution available for your (virtual) monitor.